# Python numpy broadcasting 3 dimensions (multiple weighted sums)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've become sort of used to broadcasting with 2 dimensional arrays, but I can't get my head around this 3-dimensional thing I want to do.

I have two 2-dimensional arrays:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0.01,.2,.3,.4],[.2,.03,.4,.5],[.9,.8,.7,.06]])
>>> b= np.array([[1,2,3],[3.,4,5]])
>>> a
array([[ 0.01,  0.2 ,  0.3 ,  0.4 ],
       [ 0.2 ,  0.03,  0.4 ,  0.5 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  0.8 ,  0.7 ,  0.06]])
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.]])
```

Now, what I want is the sum all rows in a, where each row is weighted by the column values in b.
So, I want `1. * a[0,:] + 2. * a[1,:] + 3. * a[2,:]` and the same for the second row of b.

So, I know how to do this step-by-step:

```
>>> (np.array([b[0]]).T * a).sum(0)
array([ 3.11,  2.66,  3.2 ,  1.58])

>>> (np.array([b[1]]).T * a).sum(0)
array([ 5.33,  4.72,  6.  ,  3.5 ])
```

But I have the feeling that if I knew how to broadcast the two correctly as 3-dimensional arrays I could get the result I want in one go.
The result being:

```
array([[ 3.11,  2.66,  3.2 ,  1.58],
       [ 5.33,  4.72,  6.  ,  3.5 ]])
```

I guess this shouldn't be too hard..?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do matrix multiplication:

```
>>> b.dot(a)
array([[ 3.11,  2.66,  3.2 ,  1.58],
       [ 5.33,  4.72,  6.  ,  3.5 ]])
```

Comment: Aaahh, it was that simple... ;-)
This way the right broadcasting will happen automagically in the background... I was thinking way too complicated. Thanks!